# Why is CBool(Command.Parameters("param").Value.IsNull) flagging as late binding?

Tags: vb.net, odp.net

I am trying to test for an OracleParameter (Output) that is null. There is a parameter property `.Value.IsNull` however, I cannot seem to test using the below as it flags as late binding by the Option Strict On project property.

```
If CBool(Command.Parameters("param").Value.IsNull) Then
```

The property is a boolean anyway, so it should just work, but even if I do CBool() shouldn't this handle the conversion?

**EDIT**

The .Value object has an .IsNull property:
[image: .Value properties]

Comment: The error message should say which item is late-bound.  I would not expect the `CBool` to have any effect on it, I would expect the issue to be with `Value` or `IsNull`.

Comment: The `Value` property of an ADO.NET parameter is type `Object`. Does the `Object` class have an `IsNull` member?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Generally speaking, a database null is not necessarily the same as `Nothing` in VB (largely because a lot of the data access stuff was written before nullable value types existed).  I don't know that it won't work in this specific case, but I'd be very suspicious that a null will end up being a `DbNull` object rather than `Nothing`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I believe it does. The ODP.NET documentation refers to an .IsNull property and when I inspect the object there is an IsNull property shown. I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Note how the debugger tells you that the type of Value is in fact Object.  Necessarily so, it can store a lot of different kind of values.  {null} is Nothing in vb.net so If Command.Parameters("param").Value IsNot Nothing ought to get the job done.

Comment: @WSC, *"I believe it does"*. Then you believe wrong. Look at the actual question I asked. If you read the documentation for the `Object` class you will see that it has no such member, so you cannot access that member on a reference of type `Object`.  What actually has that member is the `OracleString` type.  If you want to access that member then you need a reference of that type, which requires a cast. The reason it is late-binding is that you are trying to access a member of a type that can't be confirmed until run-time.

Comment: @WSC Please check my answer on how to work with oracle parameter values

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to retrieve values from `OracleParameter` is to assign value to corresponding Oracle sctructure. Because `OracleParameter.Value` contains not .NET type but Oracle Type. For example, if you expect parameter of numeric type - use `OracleDecimal`

> The OracleDecimal structure represents an Oracle NUMBER in the database or **any** Oracle numeric value.

```
Dim od As OracleDecimal = CType(Command.Parameters("param").Value, OracleDecimal)
Dim isNull As Boolean = od.IsNull
```

The `.Value.IsNull` that you see it belongs to `OracleDecimal` or other ODP Type as below. That when you browse into object. But for compiler `Value` is `Object` and object doesn't have `IsNull` defined. Hence - late binding. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDecimalStructure.htm#i1005704

Same/similar thing is for `OracleString` and `OracleDate`